# FluentUI Grouped List not rendering

Tags: fluentui-react

I'm new to react and fluentui development and am having trouble getting the Grouped List examples to work https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/groupedlist

Nothing renders until I remove the SelectionZone element. But then I can't select items.

I'm seeing the following error in the console (which doesn't mean much to me):

```
useFocusRects.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'current')
```

How should I troubleshoot this?

-- Edit --

I created a CodePen
https://codepen.io/matthewfitzmaurice/pen/NWMbXNP . But the CodePen works fine...

I've also noticed that a form that I created containing TextField, DatePicker and ComboBox has stopped working. The error occurs when I use a ComboBox. It's fine if I only use TextFields and DatePickers.

My ComboBoxes were working and now are not. This seems to indicate that I've installed something and broken some of the FluentUI controls.

Comment: Can you provide Codepen working example to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into the same issue, my problem was version related.
Updating my npm packages fixed the issue.

```
npm outdated
npm update
```